# Display tabular data. Is there any option other than looping through dataset and generating a table in razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dataset, tabular

In my MVC application, I need to display data in tabular format (no edit, only readonly) in one of the razor view. Some of the columns should be hyperlink, a couple of columns showing image, and rest columns in plain text.

I know one option is to loop through each row in the dataset (model), and build the table. Anyone has any idea if there is any other way of doing it? (without any third-party control)

Any advice on this, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Phil Haack's tabular template](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-tabular-display-template.aspx) in aspx

or [my updated version that is done in razor](http://imaginarydevelopment.blogspot.com/2013/02/autoscaffold-indexcshtml-tabular-view.html)

[About the Visual Studio Add Controller and Add View templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx)

You may also get some ideas from the `List.tt` template in `[Visual Studio Install Directory]\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\[CSharp | VisualBasic]\Web\MVC\CodeTemplates\`

[My article on changing/customizing that](http://imaginarydevelopment.blogspot.com/2013/02/change-your-mvc-addview-template.html)

Answer (score 1):

The closest "non-third party" control I can think of is the [WebGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx), but even that isn't included in the ASP.NET MVC distribution if I remember correctly (you might want to check though as I'm not 100% sure).

However, using a simple `foreach` to generate your table isn't a bad way of doing it either, especially if all you need to do is display some data.

Comment: I will check out about "WebGrid" as you suggested.. However, I am not against using "foreach" for the purpose, but I think that will low down the performance if there are some significant number of rows to populate

Comment: How many rows are you talking about? I have a feeling that the browser is going to cave in before a foreach will. Razor generates pretty efficient code for plain HTML output, and I doubt using any special control is going to be significantly (if any) more efficient. Not to mention the fact that showing a ginormous amount of rows to the user at once might not be the best idea UI-wise either. If you have too much data, include a way for the user to filter the rows.

Comment: I anticipate there would be at the max 100 rows in a single view.. not more than that.. I am also not in for 100 rows instead would like to go for paging, but that's the requirement of client to have all in single view... this wont exceed 150 rows anytime..

Comment: @Nirman: 150 rows is nothing. You don't need to worry about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Why no third-party control? Personally, I like [datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net/).